# String Concatenation and Threads in .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, string, concatenation

(Out of pure curiosity) In VB.net, I tested concatenating 100k strings and found out one thread alone did it in 23 milliseconds.  Two threads (each concatenating 50k) then joining the two at the end took 30 milliseconds.  Performance wise, it didn't seem beneficial to utilize multiple threads when dealing with only 100k concatenations.  Then I tried 3 million string concatenations and two threads each handling 1.5MM always demolished one thread handling all 3 million.  I imagine at some point using 3 threads becomes beneficial, then 4, and so on.  Is there a more efficient way to concatenate millions of strings in .NET?  Are threads worth using?

[image: At around 1MM string concatenations, it appears multiple threads can improve performance]

fyi, this is the code I wrote:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim sbOne As StringBuilder
    Dim sbTwo As StringBuilder
    Dim roof As Integer
    Dim results As DataTable
    Sub clicked(s As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        results = New DataTable
        results.Columns.Add("one thread")
        results.Columns.Add("two threads")
        results.Columns.Add("roof")

        For i As Integer = 1 To 3000000 Step 100000
            roof = i
            Dim test() As Double = runTest()
            results.Rows.Add(test(0), test(1), i)
            Console.WriteLine(roof)
        Next

        Dim output As New StringBuilder
        For Each C As DataColumn In results.Columns
            output.Append(C)
            output.Append(Chr(9))
        Next
        output.Append(vbCrLf)
        For Each R As DataRow In results.Rows
            For Each C As DataColumn In results.Columns
                output.Append(R(C))
                output.Append(Chr(9))
            Next
            output.Append(vbCrLf)
        Next
        File.WriteAllText("c:\users\username\desktop\sbtest.xls", output.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("done")

    End Sub
    Function runTest() As Double()
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Dim started As DateTime = Now
        For i As Integer = 1 To roof
            sb.Append(i)
        Next
        Dim result As String = sb.ToString
        Dim test1 As Double = Now.Subtract(started).TotalMilliseconds

        sbOne = New StringBuilder
        sbTwo = New StringBuilder
        Dim one As New Thread(AddressOf tOne)
        Dim two As New Thread(AddressOf tTwo)
        started = Now
        one.Start()
        two.Start()
        Do While one.IsAlive Or two.IsAlive
        Loop
        result = String.Concat(one.ToString, two.ToString)
        Dim test2 As Double = Now.Subtract(started).TotalMilliseconds
        Return {test1, test2}
    End Function
    Sub tOne()
        For i As Integer = 1 To roof / 2
            sbOne.Append(i)
        Next
    End Sub
    Sub tTwo()
        For i As Integer = roof / 2 To roof
            sbTwo.Append(i)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You'll probably be better off with a `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Try using the `StringBuilder` class from `System.Text`

Comment: It depends on the way You wrote your code as well as the number of cores You have. Out of curiosity: is this a research or real-world example? Also try utilizing ThreadPool (take a look at async delegates and QueueUserWOrkItem). And don't forget that thread initialization takes some time - while .NET and OS prepare new thread, your single-threaded algorithm already started concatenating. Threads are not meant for every purpose.

Comment: @HansPassant It's too bad you consider curiosity and experimentation "accomplishing nothing"

Comment: I was talking about the thread, not you :)  Use Thread.Join().

Comment: @HansPassant true join would have been better than looping and checking for the isalive

Comment: That was kinda funny in an awkward way.  Update your graph if that affected the outcome.  It should have on a two core machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the .EnsureCapacity subroutine on StringBuilder.  If you are doing a lot of concatenation and know roughly the number of characters, you can initialize the stringbuilder's buffer all at once instead of letting it happen dynamically.  You should see some more improvement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.ensurecapacity.aspx

Comment: This is good recommendation, however, it is not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: It's not? He directly asked "Is there a more efficient way to concatenate millions of strings in .NET? Are threads worth using?".  I answered that first question.  Someone else already pointed out that threads are not the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Threads are designed for tasks more expensive than string concatenation.

String concatenation involves allocating and copying memory; it's not a very comnpute-intensive task.
Multi-threading should be used when dealing with computationally intensive tasks, and to avoid blocking the UI thread.

Threading can also be useful to parallize tasks that wait on different things (eg, network IO to multiple slow servers, or network vs. disk IO)

Comment: @MarcinSeredynski: Parallelization will usually only help for compute-bound tasks.

Comment: That's pretty debatable.  The vast majority of threads are used simply for asynchronicity.  Don't block the UI.

Comment: @HansPassant: I said that in my second paragraph.

Comment: Ah, I got stuck on the mysterious first sentence :)  Maybe you ought to swap them?